# E-Commerce Database Queries to show rows as columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I am working on a E-Commerce Solution and i need some help regarding SQL Queries .

[image]

I have a database design like this.
here is live example

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d667/4

I am using this query

```
SELECT p.id as product_id, p.name as product_name, 
    pv.name AS Varient_name, pvo.name AS Varient_Option_Name, pvoc.sku_id 
FROM p p 
LEFT JOIN pv pv ON (pv.p_id = p.id) 
LEFT JOIN pvo pvo ON (pvo.pv_id = pv.id) 
LEFT JOIN pvoc pvoc ON (pvoc.pvo_id = pvo.id)
```

this query shows records like this

[image]

I want a query that show records like this:

[image]

Anyone here can help???
Waiting Thanks

Comment: The thing here is you table should have atributes size color and fabric, not entity types, you need to normalize your database

Comment: How can it be normalize? can you fiddle and produce the desired result through a query

Comment: This is for MySQL or SQL Server or both?

Comment: @gofr1 Looking at query results, it looks like phpMyAdmin, so must be MySQL. Besides that - sqlfiddle is in MySQL.

Comment: @Uzair bhai zara okaat me reh :P :P :P zara kam sawal kr

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called table transpose or pivot.

This query does that for you:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d667/80

Actual query:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pv.name = 'Size' THEN pvo.name END) AS Size,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pv.name = 'Color' THEN pvo.name END) AS Color,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pv.name = 'Fabric' THEN pvo.name END) AS Fabric,
  pvoc.sku_id,
  COUNT(*) AS Quantity
FROM p AS p
LEFT JOIN pv AS pv
  ON pv.p_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN pvo AS pvo
  ON pvo.pv_id = pv.id
LEFT JOIN pvoc AS pvoc
  ON pvoc.pvo_id = pvo.id
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, pvoc.sku_id;
```

Result from SQL Fiddle:

```
| id |       name |  Size |  Color | Fabric |                     sku_id | Quantity |
|----|------------|-------|--------|--------|----------------------------|----------|
|  1 | Men Hoodie |    XL | (null) | (null) |                     (null) |        2 |
|  1 | Men Hoodie |     M |  Black | Cotton | MH-Size-M-Color-B-Fabric-C |        3 |
|  1 | Men Hoodie |     M |  Black |  Jersy | MH-Size-M-Color-B-Fabric-J |        3 |
|  1 | Men Hoodie |     M |  White | Cotton | MH-Size-M-Color-W-Fabric-C |        3 |
|  1 | Men Hoodie |     M |  White |  Jersy | MH-Size-M-Color-W-Fabric-J |        3 |
|  1 | Men Hoodie | Small |  Black | Cotton | MH-Size-S-Color-B-Fabric-C |        3 |
|  1 | Men Hoodie | Small |  Black |  Jersy | MH-Size-S-Color-B-Fabric-J |        3 |
|  1 | Men Hoodie | Small |  White | Cotton | MH-Size-S-Color-W-Fabric-C |        3 |
|  1 | Men Hoodie | Small |  White |  Jersy | MH-Size-S-Color-W-Fabric-J |        3 |
```

Not sure why there's a NULL value in first row, but I've just used fiddle you have given us, it already had a NULL :)

Now what you have to do is - standartize Size names (such as Small = S, Large = L) and that's it.

Comment: I have last one issue that Size, Color,Fabric are not static fields.Means i can add for other product as Frame, Design and Background. I can Use that as Products variants.In that Case How Can i get that a in Query as a Heading?
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: You could use Dynamic SQL to build your query, if that tells you anything. Look for dynamic SQL examples online, is quite straightforward to understand them

Answer (score 1):

try something like this, it might give you more space to grow and less redundancy:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/361d7/1

query:

```
SELECT cloth.name, color.name, fabric.name, size.name, connect_all.id_sku, connect_all.quantity
FROM connect_all
LEFT JOIN cloth 
ON cloth.id = connect_all.id_cloth
LEFT JOIN color
ON color.id = connect_all.id_color
LEFT JOIN fabric
ON fabric.id = connect_all.id_fabric
LEFT JOIN size
ON size.id = connect_all.id_size
```

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d667/201  here you go!

```
select p.id, p.name,
max(case when pv.name = 'size' then pvo.name end) as sizes,
max(case when pv.name = 'fabric' then pvo.name end) as fabrics,
max(case when pv.name = 'color' then pvo.name end) as çolours,
sku_id, count(*) as Qty

from p inner join pv
on p.id = pv.p_id
inner join pvo
on pv.id = pvo.pv_id
inner join pvoc
on pvo.id = pvoc.pvo_id
group by p.id, p.name,sku_id;
```